# jQuery navigation with previous and next links from numbers in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, navigation

I have an array with page numbers. E.g.

```
pages (1,8,20,58,182,422,505)
```

I want to build a simple jQuery navigation without refreshing the page. My problem is with previous and next links.
I need a jQuery function/functions that cycles through the numbers in the array and bind that function/s to href links.

For example:

```
<a id="nextlink" href="#" onClick="next()">next</a> <a id="prevlink" href="#" onClick="prev()">prev</a>
```

And when I start from page 1 the next link to be '#page8'. If I click it Page 8 is loaded and the next link points to '#page20'

Comment: did you try to write something? where exactly is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to refresh the page. So the initial index of the array element is always 0. And when I clik 'next' I don't know how to increase it dynamically and how to decrease it for 'previous'.